# Spring Mongo DB - Retrieve documents based on matching elements in an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to mongo db

I have *products* collection and it contains an array of *productSeasons*

```
{
"_id" : "999999999",
"brand" : "BR",
"division" : "331",
"department" : "3314"
"productSeasons" : [
    {
        "season" : "FA",
        "year" : "2020",
        "status" : "ACTIVE",
        "design": "DESIGN1"
    },
    {
        "season" : "FA",
        "year" : "2020",
        "status" : "ACTIVE",
        "design": "DESIGN2"
    },
    {
        "season" : "SU",
        "year" : "2020",
        "status" : "ACTIVE",
        "design": "DESIGN1"
    }
]
}
```

I want to return the document with matching array elements based on season, year, status fields.
I am expecting below output for criteria, season: FA, year: 2020, status: ACTIVE
I am using spring mongo db aggregation framework

```
{
"_id" : "999999999",
"brand" : "BR",
"division" : "331",
"department" : "3314"
"productSeasons" : [
    {
        "season" : "FA",
        "year" : "2020",
        "status" : "ACTIVE",
        "design": "DESIGN1"
    },
    {
        "season" : "FA",
        "year" : "2020",
        "status" : "ACTIVE",
        "design": "DESIGN2"
    }
]
}
```

I am unable to find correct method to create AggregationExpression with multiple fields, season, year, status

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(where("_id").in(ids)),
    Aggregation.project("brand","division","department")
            .and(
                ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("productSeasons")
                    .as("productSeason")
                    .by(**ComparisonOperators.Cmp.valueOf("productSeason.season").compareTo(prodSeason.getSeason())**)
            )
            .as("productSeasons")
```

);

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below stages to get the desired output format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$productSeasons"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "productSeasons.season": "FA",
      "productSeasons.year": "2020",
      "productSeasons.status": "ACTIVE"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "department": {
        $first: "$data.department"
      },
      "productSeasons": "$data.productSeasons"
    }
  }
])
```

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UjXOg1P6w4A)

In java:

```
Aggregation.unwind
Aggregation.match
Aggregation.group
Aggregation.project
```

from the package `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation`

Answer (score 0):

In case your **MongoDB** is **4.2.8** and **Spring Data** is **3.0.3.RELEASE**, below is the Java code to create **Aggregate Expression**.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                   Aggregation.unwind("productSeasons"),
                   Aggregation.match(criteria.and("productSeasons.season").is("FA")
                           .and("productSeasons.year").is("2020")
                           .and("productSeasons.status").is("ACTIVE")), 
                   Aggregation.group("_id").push(Aggregation.ROOT).as("data"),
                   Aggregation.project("_id").and("data.brand").arrayElementAt(0).as("brand")
                                           .and("data.division").arrayElementAt(0).as("division")
                                           .and("data.department").arrayElementAt(0).as("department")
                                           .and("data.productSeasons").as("productSeasons")
                    );
AggregationResults<Product> products = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "product", Product.class);
```

Note:- You need to create 2 DTOs, **Product.java** which is main class and **ProductSeason.java** which is the class for array element to make the above code work.